# What is the minimum voltage required to make electrons flow in a vacuum diode?

Tags: electrons, vacuum

Given the hot cathode temperature, material and distance to the anode, what is the minimum voltage required to make electrons jump out of the cathode and reach the anode through vacuum? Is there a formula to calculate that? What are the typical cutoff voltage values for vacuum diodes?

Comment: Something like https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjn_4OB5b39AhUaMjQIHcK-ARMQFnoECEUQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fphysics.ucf.edu%2F~btonner%2FXRAY%2FCourses%2FExpMeth%2FThermionicEmission%2FUWA_ThermionicEmission.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2_mCyy2pdooAqTJkjoYBcL might be of interest (from Googling thermionic cathode diode emission current). Fancy coatings lower the emission barrier, but need high vacuum conditions. Space charge effects still limit the total current you can get from such a device.

Answer (score 2):

In a vacuum diode, the cathode exhibits [thermionic emission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermionic_emission): heat supplies the energy to liberate the electrons. A current flows even without any bias on the plate. It'll charge the plate to ~-1V if there's large resistance.

In the days of yore, this was sometimes used to provide "grid leak bias" for the control grids of vacuum triodes and pentodes.

Answer (score -1):

If you heat the cathode, there is no cutoff voltage.

Comment: If the cathode is hot, then zero voltage is required to make the electron flow through the vacuum diode? Did I understand correctly?

Comment: not zero but anything *above* zero....

Comment: For instance, 0,0000000001 volts will work?

Comment: I mean, how much above zero? 10 volts, 1 volt or 0,1 volts ?

Comment: @EduardOganesian It can be below zero. The current declines more or less exponentially below zero, so there's no theoretical limit. The practical limit will be something like -1V in a real device.

Comment: @ John Doty Thank you